# How to hide an element and only show it when a user starts typing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, jekyll

I am trying to incorporate a search function into my Jekyll site. I therefor decided to go with with `Simple-Jekyll-Search` which can be found here: [Link](https://github.com/christian-fei/Simple-Jekyll-Search).

This is what my `search.html` looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="my-search-input" placeholder="Search">

<div class="card">  
  <ul id="my-results-container"></ul>
</div>

<script src="/assets/javascript/simple-jekyll-search.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
SimpleJekyllSearch({
  searchInput: document.getElementById('my-search-input'),
  resultsContainer: document.getElementById('my-results-container'),
  searchResultTemplate: '[...]',
  json: '/search.json',
  noResultsText: '<li><p>No results found!</p></li>'
})
</script>
```

The search function works great so far. However the borderd card is getting shown even if nothing is getting entered. So the question is:

**How can I hide the card and only show it after the user has entered some key strokes?**

[image]

Comment: What bordered card do you mean?

Comment: Can you see my screenshot at the bottom? Sorry, its not the biggest picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide card class in your stylesheet first.

```
.card{

display:none;
}
```

and then Add following code in the script tag -

```
$(function() {
     $('#my-search-input').keyup(function() {
 if ($(this).val().length == 0) {

    $('.card').hide();
  } else {
    $('.card').show();
  }
}).keyup();
});
```

I am assuming you have added jquery in your code - If not please add following code in the head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats how I would do it (non-jquery way):

```js
function show(){
//Get the div we want gone/appeared
box=document.getElementById("box");
//Get the input
input=document.getElementById("input");

//Check if the user enterred something
if(!input.value==""){
  //If its the case set the box to visible
  box.style.display="block";
}else{
  //Else we want it gone
  box.style.display="none";
}
}
```

```css
/*SO related*/
body{background:#121212;color:white;font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/*SO related*/
#input{
background:#222222;
color:white;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid white;
}

/*Important*/
#box{
display:none;
/*SO related*/
border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter something silly:</p>
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="show();">
<div id="box">wow look i popped out</div>
</body>
</html>
```